# Error 'BOOL' does not name a type

Tags: boolean

this is the code:

```
/* the playing board is an array of these records */
typedef struct tagBOARD {
    char val;  /* the character on top face of die */
    char orient;  /* its orientation (0, 90, 180, 270 degree rotation) */
    BOOL Cused;    /* true if die was used in trying to make a word */
                  /* used only by computer in trying to find words */
    BOOL Uused;   /* true if player used letter by pushing button in */
    HWND hWindow;    /* handle of control corresponding to this die */
    char r, c;          /* row and column of this die */
    struct tagBOARD *link[8];  /* links to neighboring dice, some may be NULL */
   } BOARD;
```

but i always get this error :

```
[Error] 'BOOL' does not name a type
[Error] 'BOOL' does not name a type
[Error] 'HWND' does not name a type
```

what should i do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Include the appropriate files

Answer (score 0):

At least

```
#include <windows.h>
```

i hope that's your platform